# Why is TextAreaFor helper's rows property not settings the html rows attribute properly?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, razor-2

When I use TextAreaFor helper in MVC and I define rows like this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, 5)
```

The number of rows on this text area is not set meaning the size of the text area is not affected at all. However if I use htmlAttributes to define the rows:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { rows = 5 })
```

then it works fine. So my question is what is the rows property in TextAreaFor helper used for if not to define the rows HTML attribute of the textarea? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such overload like your first example. You may try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703460%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextAreaFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    int rows,
    int columns,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your example should be like this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes,5,10, new { @class= "myCssClassName" })
```

For your second example, you are using [the overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703546%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in the correct way.

Comment: So you're saying I have to define all these other parameters - they are not optional?

Comment: You can simply use your second approach (only provide the html attributes). You may use different overloads based on your requirements. In this case, If you simply want to specify the rows and columns, just use anyone of the above.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus That is what he is using in his second example and it works fine.